# Android - Download SQL Database and Search

Tags: android, sql

I've been working on testing trying to get an SQL database off of a website then take all the records and store them into arrays. Problem is that I've tried a ton of downloading methods and I keep getting hit with an error with opening the SQL database. I can't tell if this is actually downloading, if the database is corrupt (I checked it and it looked correct) or if my queries are messed up. Bear with me because I am just learning SQL and Android development.

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: sqlite3_open_v2("/mny/sdcard/dbdownload.sql"), &handle, 1, null) failed

Comment: sqlite returned: error code = 14 cannot open file at source line 25467

Comment: Correction: /mnt/ instead of /mny/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file at the link you provide is not a SQLite database. It's an ASCII file that contains SQL statements for creating a database and inserting content. There's no straightforward way to execute the content of that file in an Android app.

To make this work you need to create an actual SQLite database from your SQL file. To do that, install SQLite for whatever your desktop OS is and use this command:

`sqlite> .read <filename of your SQL file>`

Replace the file on your website with the SQLite file that creates. That should get you past the open error.

Comment: Yes, this was it! Reason behind it was I had been using the SQLite Database Browser and exported the files to SQL files rather than just straight up saving them. The export converted them to ASCII. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing here is download your database from url and stored it in sdcard.
Now you should open a empty database in your app and then copy your database in your app database and then try to open it.(you are not copying the database) the default location of database is

```
 private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/your package name/databases/";
```